# Getting a NotSupportedException when writing from finalizer

Tags: c#, mono, finalizer, notsupportedexception

I am trying to run the following code using Mono on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
public class X
{
    public X() { Console.WriteLine("Ctor X"); }
    ~X() { Console.WriteLine("Finalizer X"); }

    private static Y _myY = new Y();
}

public class Y
{
    public Y() { Console.WriteLine("Ctor Y"); }
    ~Y() { Console.WriteLine("Finalizer Y"); }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        X x = new X();
    }
}
```

I get the following output most of the time (always in this order, although I thought that it might change from time to time since the finalizers order of execution is not deterministic).

```
Ctor X
Ctor Y
Finalizer X
Finalizer Y
```

But every once in a while the Y finalizer throws a System.NotSupportedException that seems to be originating from the FileStream.Write method that is writing to standard output.

Any ideas why this might happen? I thought maybe the stdout handle of Console is closed before the Y finalizer runs but this is only a theory.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't genuinely want to use `Console.WriteLine` in real code. Have you considered using `Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: @Richardissimo this is not production code, of course, just some curious behavior I don't understand...

Comment: the version of ubuntu doesn't matter, what matters is the version of mono; and BTW post the **full** exception, with its message and stacktrace (exactly the text from `ex.ToString()`)

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the fact that the order of collection is non-deterministic, meaning, sometimes the `Console` static class gets collected before `Y`.

Regarding the order of execution of the constructors and destroyers, I think it's always the same because:

- The constructor of `X` is always called before `Y`'s because the default `static` constructor is called only when `X` is "touched" for the first time.
- The destroyer of `X` is always called before `Y`'s because `Y` is a static member, meaning it's a long-lived instance (i.e. [Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations)).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Like you stated, `Console` is a `static` class, hence it is not collected (there is no instance to be collected). I thought maybe there is an internal object (like a handle to stdout or something similar) that is being collected. Anyway, I thought a `static` class methods should outlive non-`static` classes, so this is still a strange behavior.

Comment: Static classes also get collect, they just get collected last. Because Y is stored in a static memeber, it also gets collected at the end, so you can never be sure which one of them will be collected first.